# Redirect both standard output and standard error to different file in the same command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, io-redirection

I am running one Linux command that throws few errors and warning and few other expected correct outputs.
I want to move those errors and warnings to different file and rest output to different file.

I know how we can Redirect both standard output and standard error to same file, but not sure about how to redirect to different file

Comment: `command > stdout.txt 2> stderr.txt`

Comment: @BrianAgnew no it is only redirecting output to file and error on screen

Comment: @TedLyngmo no it is only redirecting output to file and error on screen

Comment: when i am addin that command in a shell script and running the script as "sh test.sh 2>errorlog" it is running as expected, redirecting error to errorlog .. But i want that single command to do the above without putting into a script

Comment: Please show `test.sh` - if it opens `/dev/tty` or similar to write directly to the terminal, redirecting `stdout` from the outside won't help. If `test.sh` looks [like this](https://pastebin.com/u0mi0P7u) my suggestion will surely work